# How to move the posts index page in Wordpress to another file rather than index.php?

Tags: wordpress

The index page in Wordpress show all the posts (without comments). I would like to make the index.php a static page (not a blog), I already done that. But I don't know how to move the index of posts to other page (say blog.php).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make two new pages: 'Blog' and 'Home'.

Under Reading settings: set 'Home' as static page and 'Blog' as 'posts page'.

This makes 'Blog' utilize index.php. Then you have to setup a front-page.php and copy whatever's in your page.php as a base. Now you can edit your home page as a regular page or edit front-page.php to make changes to your home page.

Answer (score 1):

Dashboard/Settings/Reading and possibly make a page template, too, [Page Templates « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates), woith a loop.